# How to find the maximum memory utilized by one Document in MonogoDB Collection within the 30 days period?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 800k documents in the MonoDB Collection, One document({userid : '789736363828292'}) has 50k Documents/Records. I would like find the memory utilized by that particular Document({userid : '789736363828292'}) in a month or 30 days interval.

Please help me to find the memory size in MB within the Date range in monogo db console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the size of all such document using query:

```
var size = 0
db.youCollection.find({userid : '789736363828292', date:{$lt:ISODate("2018-02-25T09:13:55.996Z"), $gt: ISODate("2018-01-25T09:13:55.996Z") }}).forEach(function(doc){ size =  size + Object.bsonsize(doc)  })
print(size)
```

Comment: Thanks Astro, That query is working fine.

can you please share, how to add the date formats in the Mongodb queries...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db.col.stats()` or pipeline `$collStats` with `storageStats` to get the size of the collection

with aggregation, you can filter the document for a month or date range, write it to a new temp collection, with `stats.size` you can get size in `bytes`, divide it by `1024*1024` to get it in `MB`

collection

```
> db.temp.drop()
true
> 
> db.abc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a924393aa451c738766d20b"), "userid" : "789736363828292", "date" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a924393aa451c738766d20c"), "userid" : "789736363828292", "date" : ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a924393aa451c738766d20d"), "userid" : "789736363828292", "date" : ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a924393aa451c738766d20e"), "userid" : "789736363828292", "date" : ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a924393aa451c738766d20f"), "userid" : "789736363828292", "date" : ISODate("2018-01-05T00:00:00Z") }
```

aggregation

```
> db.abc.aggregate([
... {$match : {userid : '789736363828292', date : {$gt : new Date("2018-01-01")}, date : {$lt : new Date("2018-01-31")}}},
... {$out : "temp"}
... ])
```

size in bytes

```
> db.temp.stats().size
320
```

size in MB

```
> db.temp.stats().size/1024/1024
0.00030517578125
>
```

drop temp collection

```
> db.temp.drop()
true
>
```

`$collStats` with `storageStats`

```
> var d = db.temp.aggregate({$collStats:{storageStats: {}}}).pretty()
> d.forEach(d => print(d.storageStats.size/1024/1024))
0.00030517578125
>
```